# SolrDisMaxQuery missing from php solr?

Tags: php, solr, dismax

I've just started using Solr and I'm testing it out on OSX using:

Apache 2.2.26
PHP 5.5.20 from [here](http://php-osx.liip.ch)
This version of PHP came with the solr extension version 0.9.11.

Searching through the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php), I found that it has documentation for a SolrDisMaxQuery class. However, when attempting to instantiate an instance of this class

```
$query = new SolrDisMaxQuery('total');
```

I received an error

```
Fatal error: Class 'SolrDisMaxQuery' not found in /Users/tomsweeney/public_html/index.php on line 14
```

I know Solr is installed and working because the following works properly:

```
$query = new SolrQuery('total');
```

I attempted installing the latest extension version (2.0.0), verified that it was properly installed with solr_get_version(), but the error still persists.

I even searched through the full source code of the extension for "dismax" but it doesn't exist.

Did this class ever exist in this extension? Or should I just switch to something like Solarium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SolrDisMaxQuery` class was not part of the 2.0.0 release.

You can still download the current [master branch sources](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/search_engine/solr.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/master) (there is some new stuff including dismax), and see what you can do with it.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that 2.0.0 wasn't the latest. Thanks for the link!